# Android layout issue with buttons below WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a webview I'd like to display as a dialog. I'd like the webview to fill the entire screen, except for a button below it that I'd like to stay at the bottom of the dialog regardless of how much content is in the webview. Currently my webview fills up the dialog just enough to push the button off the screen. I'm sure this is something pretty easy but for the life of me, I haven't been able to find the magical combination of layouts, views and attribute values to get it to play nice. Just to be clear, I've gotten it so the button floats over the webview but I'd like the webview to stop just above the button and scroll, if that makes sense.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           /> 
  <Button android:text="Ok" 
          android:id="@+id/btnOk" 
          android:layout_width="120px" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to use android:layout_above="@+id/btnOk" for your webview, and do fill_parent for width and height of the webview.

However, it is important to note, that in 1.5 and below, RelativeLayout views need to be specified in order in your xml to be recognized correctly.. in other words, you have to have your Button first, then the WebView, since the WebView will reference the button. I think this has been changed in 1.6 or 2.0, but I am not positive which.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <Button android:text="Ok" 
          android:id="@+id/btnOk" 
          android:layout_width="120px" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
           android:layout_above="@+id/btnOk"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You sir, are my new favorite person. Even after months of Android development I'm still learning some of these basic things. You have my gratitude!

Comment: It is 1.6 that fixes forward reference problems:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html